# Not print correct ObservableLong

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.0.1, Java 1.8, Gradle 4.2
In my fragment:

```
public final ObservableLong dateFromMills = new ObservableLong();
```

here method than convert date to string:

```
public static String getDateAsString(long date, String pattern) {
        return getDateAsString(new Date(date), pattern);
    }

    // if pattern is null then will be use defaultDTCDateFormat
    public static String getDateAsString(Date date, String pattern) {
        if (date == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
        try {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            return sdf.format(date);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            return sdf.format(date);
        }
}
```

And here xml layout that use this method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>    
        <import type="android.view.View" />    
        <import type="com.myproject.android.common.util.date.DateUtil" />  

    </data>

    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dateFromTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text='@{DateUtil.getDateAsString(handler.dateFromMills, "dd.MM.yyyy")' />

</layout>
```

But as result in text view print

```
@{DateUtil.getDateAsString(handler.dateFromMills, "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

[image]

But if I used this:

```
android:text='@{item.date != null ? DateUtil.getDateAsString(item.date, "MM/yy") : ""}'
```

It's success work. `item.date` has type `java.util.Date`

Why with **ObservableLong**  not work?

Comment: Can you copy the error message? We cannot actually see the problem from your screenshot.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. I suggest using an `Instant` instead of your `ObservableLong`. To generate a string, assign a `ZoneId` to generate a `ZonedDateTime`, extract a `LocalDate`, and specify a `Locale` rather than a formatting pattern to let `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` automatically localize. `Instant.ofEpochMilli( myLong ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).toLocalDate().format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) )`

Comment: No error message. Date is not convert  to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the missing "}" in your binding? Generally I would recomment to bind to a [controller/presenter](https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/) class, which internally uses `DateUtil` instead of using it directly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm forgot the close "}". Thanks